npm ERR No version available for browser-assert when install @storybook/builder-webpack5
Trying to install @storybook/builder-webpack5 for a project but face error.
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for browser-assert
Any suggestion for work around this?
I tried in install browser-assert separate but they said no version available as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
